# Maven clean package lead to random "Application failed to start"

Tags: maven, spring-boot, yaml, jhipster

I encounter a very strange issue with my jhipster application (Spring Boot + Angular, v5.0.2).
**Randomly**, maven compilation (./mvnw -Pprod clean package -DskipTests) give me a war that cannot be executed : I can compile and launch the war and all work fine, and one minute later, **without any change**, I can compile but when I launch the war I get this stack trace :

```
11:46:32.286 [main] ERROR org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication - Application run failed
java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: org.yaml.snakeyaml.Yaml.<init>(Lorg/yaml/snakeyaml/constructor/BaseConstructor;Lorg/yaml/snakeyaml/representer/Representer;Lorg/yaml/snakeyaml/DumperOptions;Lorg/yaml/snakeyaml/LoaderOptions;Lorg/yaml/snakeyaml/resolver/Resolver;)V
```

This behaviour is seen on my laptop, my collegue laptop, and a Jenkins Docker image, so does not seem to be an environment issue.

** EDIT : **

Here is the pom : http://jsfiddle.net/ewn6qLzd/ (sorry I did not found something more appropriate to share it)

Any help would be much appreciated.
Best Regards,

Comment: It looks like you either have multiple SnakeYAML jars in the war file and their order is changed, or you have one SnakeYAML jar in the war file and its version is changed. You could, perhaps, confirm this by looking at the contents of the war that works and the war that doesn't.

Comment: better share pom.xml as well.